# XMLHttpRequest cannot load with Socket.io in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I am currently using Socket.io npm module running with ExpressJS in my server at port 5555. In my client side, I am using io.connect to my localhost:5555 which is my server inside AngularJS controller. My client side returns XMLHttpRequest continuously. In my server side, I had used

> app.use(cors())
>
> app.use(cors("http://localhost:6666"))

But still no luck.

**Client Side** running at localhost:6666

```
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:5555");
```

**Server Side** running at localhost:5555

```
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT;
io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'xhr-polling', 'jsonp-polling', 'htmlfile', 'flashsocket']);
io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

Error Message:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   localhost:5555/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=LVsapo4.
>   Credentials flag is 'true', but the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials'
>   header is ''. It must be 'true' to allow credentials. Origin
>   'localhost:6666' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Have you tried it without the second cors intialization?

Comment: @bflemi3 yea still not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this in your express server code

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
   next();
});
```

instead of the code that you are currently using.

Comment: I had removed all the cors and io sets and added your codes. Error still the same, not working.

Answer (score 0):

## Please try this and see if it works

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var httpServer = require('http').Server(app);
    const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
      cors: {
        origin: "https://example.com",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"]
      }
    });
```